If the laws of nature are not metaphysically fundamental, what alternative explanations could account for the regularities observed in nature?
Suppose, for the sake of argument, that the answer to Are there laws of Nature? is "no"—there are no metaphysically fundamental laws causing the universe to behave regularly. If we rule out this explanation, what other explanations could account for the existence of regularity in the way the universe behaves?

Addendum - Humean and anti-Humean views of the laws of nature
Probably the correct technical term I should use to denote metaphysically fundamental laws is the anti-Humean view(s) of the laws of nature. Simply put, an anti-Humean view of the laws of nature would say that the laws of nature are not merely human descriptions of seemingly emergent patterns, but rather fundamental constraints governing how the world should behave (like actual rules governing how a simulation should run, if I may draw an analogy with computer programs).
But in order to have a more authoritative source to back up my claims, the following are some excerpts from Harjit Bhogal's article Humeanism about Laws of Nature:

Abstract
Humeanism about laws of nature is, roughly, the view that the laws of nature are just patterns, or ways of describing patterns, in the mosaic of events. In this paper I survey some of the (many!) objections that have been raised to Humeanism, considering how the Humean might respond. And I consider how we might make a positive case for Humeanism. The common thread running through all this is that the viability of the Humean view relies on the Humean having an importantly different conception of explanation to the anti-Humean.
[...]
Humeanism about laws of nature is an approach to scientific laws which denies that laws imply necessary connections between distinct existences. Roughly, the idea is that laws of nature reduce to the patterns of occurrent, non-modal, events that occur in the world. The
laws of nature are just patterns, or ways of describing patterns, in the mosaic of events. So, there is no problem with necessary connections between the laws and particular events, since the laws and the particular events are not distinct existences.
(Candidate laws of nature are things like Schrödinger’s equation, or the law of conservation of energy. Whether there are laws of nature about higher-level sciences, like biology or economics, is an interesting question that we will put aside.)
The Humean view stands in opposition to anti-Humean views which typically claim that laws are over and above the patterns of events and, in fact, that the laws govern those events, rather than merely describing them. (Although not all anti-Humean approaches think of
laws as this separate, governing entity. See Hildebrand (2020) for an excellent survey of anti-Humean approaches.)
To be more precise, Humeanism about laws of nature is the view that the laws of nature reduce to the Humean Mosaic — that is, the intrinsic physical state of each spacetime point (or each pointlike object) and the spatio-temporal relations between those points — and
that the Humean Mosaic is not further reduced to anything else.


Aside from intelligent design, by God or aliens or simulators, and multiverse with variable physics, there is an evolutionary option. As C.S. Peirce put it, "matter is effete mind, inveterate habits becoming physical laws." A materialist version was developed by Nancy Cartwright, "laws of nature obtain... on account of the repeated operation of a system of components with stable capacities in particularly fortunate circumstances", i.e. through what she calls "nomological machine". Habits or machines develop from the more irregular substrate.

@Conifold “stable capacities in particularly fortunate circumstances” involves order and thus laws at best. And at worst, it would just assert that order comes from disorder, but asserting it does not make it so. Modern biological evolution is also underpinned by laws.

Note strong overlap with https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/120182/is-there-greater-explanatory-power-in-laws-governing-things-rather-than-being-de

Indeed perhaps individual descriptive hypothesis or theory cannot account for the regularities observed in nature, but a manifold of them like the old pre-established or prescribed Indra's Net covering the observable base not unlike a constant self-sustaining feedback strange loop could be a different story. After all the law of large numbers yielding a regular normal distribution almost surely hints there's a hidden background congregational bi-directional net to ensure the independent samplings from the said identical self-subsistent ever-negotiating feedback loopy net...

I read part of the paper you linked to, but I cannot really take it seriously. Did any physicist review it? Also, the author of the paper defends the "Humean view". If the Humean view is dubious, the anti view, as presented, seems even more so, since it seems to make stronger claims about "necessary links" (which I don't think any physicist needs to admit to if they care at all about this kind of picturing).

In other words, I don't quite see, how this paper motivates this question.

Laws of Nature can only be explained in terms of something else that is not like a law. So laws are non-lawful, ultimately. Explanations unexplain themselves into inexplicable things. Would the Humean Mosaic satisfy you? If not, what would? If there were laws ultimately, what would they be encoded in, other than the universe and how it is?

@mudskipper Perhaps Conifold might be a better source to motivate the Humean / anti-Humean dichotomy? https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/q/19631/80226

What's wrong with things being physically fundamental, without resorting to metaphysics? (This could be argued to be an Answer...)

@keshlam it may be not unlike stub/skeleton duals in Java client/server communications with RMI interface via its underlying JRMP protocol such as Weblogic, the client stub is here within physical closure calling for some missing implementation from the metaphysical yonder skeleton over miles and miles away or at the edges, though its users may never figure out the very existence of such a latent intricate protocol to further communicate and discover...

@DoubleKnot As I said elsewhere, sure it's possible, but (a) I have trouble imagining any way to test it, (2) it doesn't seem to resolve any current complexity or give us any useful answers, and (III) it does seem to create new issues to be addressed. As such, I have no interest in it; it feels like complication for the sake of complication. That may be my own limited vision, it may be Occam's Razor which is admittedly a human preference but still useful for prioritizing. If others want to pursue it, more power to them but to me it looks like a solution in search of a problem.

Alternatives that could "account" for the regularity that has been observed thus far:

we are simulated
all observations so far are the result of an extremely lucky path through randomness
there is a God
solipsism
we are dreaming
you just came into existence only long enough to have this current thought
frogs are causing it all

In fact, without underlying fundamental laws (even if ultimately inaccessible to us), anything could be an account for what we experience, since there would be no fundamental law preventing it. Note, many of these accounts are incapable of predicting the next experience. Many do not depend on there being a next experience. And many of these accounts lack explanatory power.
And in a different sense, whatever the alternative explanation is would itself be the fundamental law(s), generating a contradiction in your question.

If our Frogs overlords permit it, I'll go with last Thursdayism...

Lowri, I added an addendum to my question for clarification. Letting you know in case you may feel the need to edit something in response.

@Syed This is incorrect, an explanation need only be capable of explaining why something happened, not capable of predicting what will happen in the future. Ephemeral comments are not the place for such debate, but it seems like a valid question for this SE if it interests you enough to ask it.

@JackAidley No, by prediction, I meant what is expected by the hypothesis, not necessarily something in the future. Nothing about the god or the simulation hypothesis explains our observations since there is nothing within it that implies our observations unless you gerrymander the observations into the hypothesis itself

A provocative answer:
There is a branch of mathematics called Ramsey theory, which studies mathematical phenomena where large collections inevitably have some small bits of order.  For example, assuming any two people are either acquaintances or strangers, then if you have a very large group of people, there will be either at least 10 people who are mutual acquaintances or 8 people who are mutual strangers.  This holds if 10 and 8 are replaced by any numbers (but very large gets very very large very quickly - the precise minimum number is not known, but for 10 and 8 "very large" is some number known to be between 343 and 4402.)
So assuming the universe is generally disordered, there will still be patterns or approximate patterns to find.  Our minds focus on patterns, so we lock onto those and think those are the laws of the universe, and don't even notice all the many other aspects that have no structure.

I feel as if this is merely a theoretical position that makes people feel good but that there is no actual evidence of this. Most of the processes that we model as random like dice rolls or coin tosses or even statistical processes are not really random, neither are human relations in your example. They all internally follow ordered processes and hence laws, so you are not getting any order from disorder. The only legitimate avenue for random processes are in quantum mechanics but that is merely an interpretation of QM. Others are deterministic fully

It's not intended to make people feel good - in fact, if anything, this should be pretty scary. Just like the actual (but speculative) physical theory that the universe could just suddenly go poof (that is, completely end as we know it) due to vacuum decay.

I've edited out the word 'random' because that's a red herring.  I didn't mean random as in 'coming from a stochastic process' - I just meant random as in 'having no discernable order'.

The very limited precision with which we can make measurements, and the extremely limited ways in which we can make things crash into eachother, may also strengthen this argument. (So I'll suspend my judgement until we can construct a Dyson sphere.)

I don't undersatnd why you call your answer provocative.

Indeed. I also don't find this provocative, but congenial. Almost the perfect anti-finetuning argument I've been looking for :)

What we mean when we say "laws of nature" are high level rules or equations in our descriptions of how objects and forces, etc, in the real world behave. Newton's three laws, Einstein's Theory of relatively, Hook's law, Quantum dynamics, and so on. But even if these laws perfectly described the universe it is almost impossible for these laws to actually be governing its behaviour.
Why?
Because laws of nature are large scale descriptions of mass action, and there is nothing in the universe within our descriptions that could possibly be orchestrating those actions. Newton's second law does not contain an actuary totting up the mass or force; nor is the mass of a Newtonian object a fundamental property of that object but rather a collective property of billions of component parts. Instead, the actual behaviour of the universe is caused by the behaviour of entities (quarks, leptons, whatever) in their interactions with each other and it is these behaviours that are fundamental.
Our laws do not describe these actual behaviours, they describe the collective action of vast numbers of these behaviours. Even quantum mechanics, the closest we have to anything that works at this level, can only describe them in terms of probabilities.

I suspect that some will look at this and go "ah! But the behaviour of those fundamental whatevers they are the real laws of nature". In answer to that: firstly, I think you are completely redefining the concept of "laws of nature" by doing this and in a way that renders the concept meaninglessly broad, making it "any regularity of any thing is a law of nature", and that in turn makes the question a tautology. Secondly, I think the idea that the behaviour of things being consistent means they are governed by laws to be a category error: the behaviour is the fundamental here not the rule that describes it.

Since time immemorial science formulates better and better laws of nature in our universe.
If you assume that there are no laws of nature, then you consider a different universe, which is totally unknown to us.
Hence your question makes no sense.
Added to avoid any misunderstanding of my answer's first line.
I consider the laws of nature to be descriptive: Our successfull scientific theories formulate laws, which describe and explain the phenomena in accordance with observation.
But we cannot put ourself in the position of the universe and imagine how these laws look from the viewpoint of the universe - don’t explain the universe on the basis of an anthropomorphic model.
Of course the universe existed long before humans and their theories and laws of nature. Therefore it is reasonable to assume that the universe does not care for our theories, and that our laws are not prescriptive for the universe.

And yet, there are highly upvoted answers like this one that suggest that the universe doesn't follow any rules.

Of course the laws of nature are descriptive, not prescriptive. That's the meaning of "the universe does not follow any rules".

Then you are contradicting yourself, or you need to explain yourself better, because you seem to be saying that the universe doesn't follow any rules and yet you say it follows laws, and rules and laws are synonyms.

@user80226 The fact that the universe behaves consistently is not a rule, it's simply something we've observed. There's nothing that requires it, but it has always been true.

@Barmar Then you clearly agree with the linked answer, and clearly disagree with Jo (since Jo claims that there are indeed laws of nature fundamentally, metaphysically).

@user80226 The problem is that "follows rule" can have different interpretations. It doesn't follow rules that we create, it has consistent patterns that we then describe as rules/laws.

@Barmar My question is about metaphysically fundamental laws of nature, as part of the fundamental ontology of reality. Jo seems to be saying that those do exist, and therefore my question would be nonsense. However, the linked answer seems to clearly disagree. Now, my question is asking you to assume, for the sake of argument, that there are NO metaphysically fundamental laws of nature. How would you explain the observed regularity then?

@user80226 - There are indeed no "metaphysically fundamental laws of nature" - unless by that you mean the laws discovered in physics. Otherwise, what other laws would you want? How could anything be more "fundamental"?

@mudskipper The technical term (that I probably should've used) is the anti-Humean view of the laws of nature. Read the third paragraph on page 2 of this paper.

@mudskipper I edited my question with an addendum. I hope it helps.

@Barmar See above.

@JoWehler I think you're still using "laws of nature" in two different ways in your answer here in a way that contributes to the ongoing misunderstanding. You're conflating the underlying principles by which the universe functions with the models developed by physics to describe those principles. It doesn't make sense to refer to the laws of nature as both discovered and descriptive, unless you also consider, for example, the contents of a report on the results of reverse-engineering a chip as also having been discovered rather than created. (cont.)

@JoWehler What we discover is the results of a large number of individual experiments which are then formed into a gestalt with which we then create descriptive laws of nature to describe the overall patterns suggested by those experiments. But that's very different from discovering the laws themselves. And it's this conflation that leads to a lot of confusion on this topic in this StackExchange.

@Idran I agree with you and changed the first and - in a minor way - the last sentence of my answer. Thanks.

There is no way to explain a regularity without positing a law that governs it, or some sort of power that inherently follows that law.
Think of a computer program that follows a certain pattern: 2 4 6 8 10 12 14 16 18 20. What explains this? A computer program that inherently codifies a law, a law that can be represented in mathematics: X + 2 iterated in a loop.
Sure, the universe isn’t a computer program, but there is no reason to think that the universe isn’t obeying metaphysically fundamental laws, given the obvious fact that it obeys many, unbreakable patterns.
The only alternative is to posit that all of these patterns are mere coincidences and that the reason the cup stays on the same table it is on is by pure, unexplained coincidence.

This discussion is basically backwards.
The regularity of the observed universe is what we are trying to explain.  The regularity is the law empirically because it is observed.  We are describing what we observe, in detail to understand it better and to make predictions based upon our explanations.  We are the ones who posit/model "laws" in nature based on what is observed.  Nature is fundamentally regular only as well as our descriptions of it as regular are correct.
If you do not have an explanation for that observed regularity, how it actually arises then it is simply unexplained.
We couldn't or wouldn't know what is fundamental or why until we had such an explanation, metaphysics doesn't enter into it, just physics.
Trying to limit the possible ways regularity could arise in a system such as the universe is getting ahead of yourself.
